ProcessError: warning: failed to remove _next/static/.../: Permission Denied
I have a React project with NextJS and I tried running npm run deploy (executing gh-pages -d out) but it gives me the following error:
> project@0.1.0 predeploy
> npm run build


> project@0.1.0 build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 15.1.2

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
 ✓ Collecting page data
 ✓ Generating static pages (4/4)
 ✓ Collecting build traces
 ✓ Exporting (3/3)
 ✓ Finalizing page optimization

Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    206 kB          312 kB
└ ○ /_not-found                          979 B           107 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            106 kB
  ├ chunks/4bd1b696-1d398b649b281e55.js  52.9 kB
  ├ chunks/517-056b7465b3216e08.js       50.6 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)          1.99 kB


○  (Static)  prerendered as static content


> project@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d out

ProcessError: warning: failed to remove _next/static/8FM1BF8OK1Exh6Ewqsqjb/: Permission denied

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\realhuman\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\project\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:42:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:524:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1101:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)

I have ran npm run deploy before and it's worked perfectly previously - now I'm not sure what happened but it always gives me this error. I've tried the following:

Deleting the pre-generated .next/ and out/ folders
Restarting my computer
Running from administrator
Re-installing npm and NodeJS with nvm
Re-installing my Node modules

Nothing seems to work. Note that when running npm run dev the development version works perfectly with no errors.
I'm running Powershell version 7.4.6 on Windows 11 with npm version 10.9.0 and NodeJS version v22.12.0. I haven't changed anything to the source GitHub repository which I have full ownership to.
Is there anything else I'm missing? What can I do to fix this issue?

Not sure if this is an official fix, but I fixed this by re-cloning the Git repository. I have no clue why this worked but it worked.
